# Connection error while connecting linode mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, linode

I have installed mogodb linode "mongodb-app" and its running .. created user and collections and able to access it from shell
now trying to connect to the server from my local but getting server timeout
'''

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 170.187.248.15:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6218a8cccb94c35a2569ce55, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('170.187.248.15', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('170.187.248.15:27017: timed out')>]>

default_config = {'MONGODB_SETTINGS': {
#Local DB
'db': 'test_db',
'host': 'localhost',
'port': 27017

#linode "mongodb-app"
'db': '<db name>',
'host': '<server ip>',
'port': 27017,
'username': '<db user>,
'password': '<db password>',
'authentication_source': 'admin'
}
```

'''
I have followed couple of steps :
'''

```
1. updated /etc/mongod.conf from the server
    net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp:0.0.0.0
```

'''

```
2. sudo ufw status
    sudo: unable to resolve host 170-187-248-15
    Status: active

    To                         Action      From
    --                         ------      ----
    22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
    27017                      ALLOW       0.0.0.0
    22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

but still facing the same error

Comment: It looks like on the server your have `27017  ALLOW   0.0.0.0` instead of ALLOW Anywhere (or the ip of your app)?

Comment: thanks @jamomani, but doesn't 0.0.0.0 mean any IP it will allow.

Answer (score 1):

On your linux server where mongodb is running, run these two commands:

`iptables -A INPUT -s <ip-address-of-your-app> -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ip-address-of-your-app> -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Taken from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/#traffic-to-and-from-mongod-instances

Comment: thanks @jamomani, I have ran the commands with my local ip but still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have a router in front of the server? If you do, you need to allow port forwarding to your server.

Comment: Thank you. A restart after these worked for me. You can use this command to restart MongoDB: sudo systemctl restart mongod.service